# Mailman sending messages as wrong domain

Tags: exim, mailman

I've got mailman and exim on my server for our mailing lists. When you send a message to it ( testlist@bar.company.com ), the message sender is testlist@foo.company.com.  This server is locally known as foo.company.com, with bar.company.com as an alias. foo.company.com is the servers internal name, while bar.company.com is what outsiders see. How can I get mailman to send from bar.company.com rather than foo?

Comment: Is this showing up in the From, Reply-To, or Return-Path headers?

Comment: Messages come from the sender, as the lists are set up. the reply-to address is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Check, please, in web interface for list what you have in in General section in host_name. You should have bar.company.com here. You can also explicit set reply_to_address in same section.